# fixing prisma dynamic table name with date

Tags: mysql, express, prisma

I have a function for querying MySQL with Prisma in Express.js, and currently, I am stuck with one issue. Here is the function:

```
    const createUpdateRoleMenu = async () => {
    try {
      const currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '');
      const tableName = `app_role_menu_${currentDate}`;

      const roleMenu = await dscClient.$transaction([
        dscClient.$executeRaw`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${tableName} LIKE app_role_menu;`,
        dscClient.$executeRaw`INSERT INTO ${tableName} SELECT * FROM app_role_menu;`,
        dscClient.$executeRaw`UPDATE ${tableName} SET allowed = 0 WHERE menu_id IN (
        'GRP-DA-EF-P2P-NEW', 'GRP-DA-P2P', 'GRP-DA-P2PNEW', 'GRP-DA-TOR-P2PACT',
        'GRP-DA-TOR-P2PVER', 'GRP-DU-SIM-MGGR', 'GRP-DU-SIM-MGGR-NEW'
      );`
      ]);

      console.log('Operation successfully.');
      return roleMenu;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error occurred:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  };

  createUpdateRoleMenu().catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error while executing the function:', error);
  });
```

The issue there is that currentDate seems to be interpreted as a parameter, or its format is not accepted by Prisma. The error in the vscode terminal is:

```
[2024-03-21 15:37:10] error: {"timestamp":"2024-03-21T08:37:10.512Z","message":"\nInvalid `prisma.$executeRaw()` invocation:\n\n\nRaw query failed. Code: `1064`. Message: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? LIKE app_role_menu' at line 1`","target":"$executeRaw"}
[2024-03-21 15:37:10] error: {"timestamp":"2024-03-21T08:37:10.516Z","message":"Raw query failed. Code: `1064`. Message: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? LIKE app_role_menu' at line 1`","target":"$executeRaw"}
[2024-03-21 15:37:10] error: {"timestamp":"2024-03-21T08:37:10.520Z","message":"Raw query failed. Code: `1064`. Message: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? LIKE app_role_menu' at line 1`","target":"$executeRaw"}
Error occurred: PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.$executeRaw()` invocation:

Raw query failed. Code: `1064`. Message: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? LIKE app_role_menu' at line 1`
    at Rn.handleRequestError (C:\_OJT-FS-DAnS_DSC\db-query-app-api\node_modules\@internal\prisma-dsc\client\runtime\library.js:174:7325)  
    at Rn.handleAndLogRequestError (C:\_OJT-FS-DAnS_DSC\db-query-app-api\node_modules\@internal\prisma-dsc\client\runtime\library.js:174:6754)
    at Rn.request (C:\_OJT-FS-DAnS_DSC\db-query-app-api\node_modules\@internal\prisma-dsc\client\runtime\library.js:174:6344) {
  code: 'P2010',
  clientVersion: '4.16.2',
  meta: {
    code: '1064',
    message: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax 
to use near '? LIKE app_role_menu' at line 1"
  }
}
```

When I try to use a static name, it works. For example, app_role_menu_20240321.

I would appreciate any help with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$executeRaw` doesn't support using template variables ([documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/queries/raw-database-access/raw-queries#executeraw)).

However, you do have the option to use `$executeRawUnsafe`:

```js
const roleMenu = await dscClient.$transaction([
  dscClient.$executeRawUnsafe`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${tableName} LIKE app_role_menu;`,
  // other statements
      ]);
```

See documentation here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/queries/raw-database-access/raw-queries#executerawunsafe

As always, **the warning against SQL injection attacks** and using raw user input in any SQL statement applies. But if you're forming the table name yourself, you should be good to go.